# CastError when open link to static file in Jade, Nodejs

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose, pug

Project on Node.js, Express, Jade

Here is route for getting user

```
// Get Single User
router.get('/view/:id', auth.ensureManager, function (req, res) {
...
}
```

and here is some logic inside it (2 mongoose models: Subscribe (`user_id` field is unique) and Order)

```
Subscribe.findOne().where({user_id: req.params.id}).exec(function (err, subscribe) {
  if (!err) {
       Order.find()
            .where({user_id: req.params.id})
            .sort('-createdAt')
            .exec(function (err, orders) {
                 if (err) {
                      res.status(500).send();
                 } else {
                      res.render('users/view', {
                         receipt: (subscribe) ? cryptr.decrypt(subscribe.receipt) : null,
                         orders: orders,
                         subscribe: subscribe
                      });
                 }
       });
 }
});
```

receipt is generated link (for example - `/subscribes/gil/receipt.jpg`) to image/pdf file which stored in `public/storage` path

In jade i get this link and render

```
if (receipt)
   li.list-group.margin-bottom  Receipt:&nbsp;
      a(href='/storage/' + receipt, target='_blank') view
```

And when I go to this link image is opening, but i recieve the **CastError in console**, like this:

```
{ CastError: Cast to ObjectId failed for value "undefined" at path "_id" for model "Subscribe"
    at new CastError (E:\Work\OSPanel\domains\tradecluster-node\node_modules\mongoose\lib\error\cast.js:27:11)
    at ObjectId.cast (E:\Work\OSPanel\domains\tradecluster-node\node_modules\mongoose\lib\schema\objectid.js:158:13)
    at ObjectId.SchemaType.applySetters (E:\Work\OSPanel\domains\tradecluster-node\node_modules\mongoose\lib\schematype.js:724:12)
    at ObjectId.SchemaType._castForQuery (E:\Work\OSPanel\domains\tradecluster-node\node_modules\mongoose\lib\schematype.js:1095:15)
    at ObjectId.castForQuery (E:\Work\OSPanel\domains\tradecluster-node\node_modules\mongoose\lib\schema\objectid.js:198:15)
    at ObjectId.SchemaType.castForQueryWrapper (E:\Work\OSPanel\domains\tradecluster-node\node_modules\mongoose\lib\schematype.js:1064:15)
    at cast (E:\Work\OSPanel\domains\tradecluster-node\node_modules\mongoose\lib\cast.js:300:32)
    at model.Query.Query.cast (E:\Work\OSPanel\domains\tradecluster-node\node_modules\mongoose\lib\query.js:3198:12)
    at model.Query.Query._castConditions (E:\Work\OSPanel\domains\tradecluster-node\node_modules\mongoose\lib\query.js:1278:10)
    at model.Query.Query._findOne (E:\Work\OSPanel\domains\tradecluster-node\node_modules\mongoose\lib\query.js:1494:8)
    at model.Query.Query.findOne (E:\Work\OSPanel\domains\tradecluster-node\node_modules\mongoose\lib\query.js:1611:8)
    at Function.findOne (E:\Work\OSPanel\domains\tradecluster-node\node_modules\mongoose\lib\model.js:1500:13)
    at Function.findById (E:\Work\OSPanel\domains\tradecluster-node\node_modules\mongoose\lib\model.js:1426:15)
    at E:\Work\OSPanel\domains\tradecluster-node\routes\users.js:176:15
    at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (E:\Work\OSPanel\domains\tradecluster-node\node_modules\express\lib\router\layer.js:95:5)
    at next (E:\Work\OSPanel\domains\tradecluster-node\node_modules\express\lib\router\route.js:137:13)
    at ensureManager (E:\Work\OSPanel\domains\tradecluster-node\components\auth.js:15:16)
    at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (E:\Work\OSPanel\domains\tradecluster-node\node_modules\express\lib\router\layer.js:95:5)
    at next (E:\Work\OSPanel\domains\tradecluster-node\node_modules\express\lib\router\route.js:137:13)
    at Route.dispatch (E:\Work\OSPanel\domains\tradecluster-node\node_modules\express\lib\router\route.js:112:3)
    at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (E:\Work\OSPanel\domains\tradecluster-node\node_modules\express\lib\router\layer.js:95:5)
    at E:\Work\OSPanel\domains\tradecluster-node\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:281:22
  message: 'Cast to ObjectId failed for value "undefined" at path "_id" for model "Subscribe"',
  name: 'CastError',
  stringValue: '"undefined"',
  kind: 'ObjectId',
  value: 'undefined',
  path: '_id',
  reason: undefined,
  model: 
   { [Function: model]
     hooks: Kareem { _pres: [Object], _posts: [Object] },
     base: 
      Mongoose {
        connections: [Array],
        models: [Object],
        modelSchemas: [Object],
        options: [Object],
        _pluralize: [Function: pluralize],
        plugins: [Array] },
     modelName: 'Subscribe',
     model: [Function: model],
     db: 
      NativeConnection {
        base: [Object],
        collections: [Object],
        models: [Object],
        config: [Object],
        replica: false,
        hosts: null,
        host: 'localhost',
        port: 27017,
        user: null,
        pass: null,
        name: 'ldex',
        options: null,
        otherDbs: [],
        relatedDbs: {},
        states: [Object],
        _readyState: 1,
        _closeCalled: false,
        _hasOpened: true,
        _listening: false,
        _connectionOptions: [Object],
        '$initialConnection': [Object],
        _events: [Object],
        _eventsCount: 1,
        db: [Object],
        client: [Object] },
     discriminators: undefined,
     '$appliedMethods': true,
     '$appliedHooks': true,
     schema: 
      Schema {
        obj: [Object],
        paths: [Object],
        aliases: {},
        subpaths: {},
        virtuals: [Object],
        singleNestedPaths: {},
        nested: {},
        inherits: {},
        callQueue: [],
        _indexes: [],
        methods: [Object],
        statics: {},
        tree: [Object],
        query: {},
        childSchemas: [],
        plugins: [Array],
        s: [Object],
        _userProvidedOptions: [Object],
        options: [Object],
        '$globalPluginsApplied': true,
        _requiredpaths: [Array] },
     collection: 
      NativeCollection {
        collection: [Object],
        opts: [Object],
        name: 'subscribes',
        collectionName: 'subscribes',
        conn: [Object],
        queue: [],
        buffer: false,
        emitter: [Object] },
     Query: { [Function] base: [Object] },
     '$__insertMany': [Function],
     '$init': Promise { [Circular], catch: [Function] } } }
```

At the same time, if I copy this link (http://localhost:3000/storage/subscribes/gil/receipt.jpg) and paste it directly to browser, and even more click 'Open in new tab' on link in window I see image and **no errors in console**.

**UPD**
Object subscribe is

```
{
    "payed": true,
    "_id": "5abb6057d1eb870ba056be7c",
    "user_id": "5abb6023d1eb870ba056be7b",
    "requisites": "Tinkoff, card number 0000 0000 0000 0000",
    "interval": 6,
    "currency": 3,
    "cost": 2500,
    "createdAt": "2018-03-28T09:28:55.707Z",
    "updatedAt": "2018-03-28T09:49:24.882Z",
    "__v": 0,
    "receipt": "a735d0dda919f0a9bcf54fd6e41691cfd521eb6547c352c606b2220ad27aa91a2c0a4c3ec47c031967e4fec41425378c",
    "paid_till": "2018-09-28T09:49:24.875Z"
}
```

Comment: Could you paste `subscribe` object in your question? Use `JSON.stringify(subscribe)` and try to paste the response here.

Comment: Yes, of course, added...

Comment: It's very strange, why i recieve this error only if going from Jade rendered link, if I go directly or as "In new tab" all OK...

Comment: What is with this line `a(href='/storage/' + receipt, target='_blank')`? `receipt` is an object, isn't it?

Comment: No, receipt is simple String part of url (in this case to image), it's decrypting from crypted String (`a735d0dda919f0a9bcf54fd6e41691cfd521eb6547c352c606b2220ad27aa91a2c0a4c3ec47c031967e4fec41425378c`) to readable part (`/subscribes/gil/receipt.jpg`) so this line `a(href='/storage/' + receipt, target='_blank')` is goes to `a(href='/storage/' + '/subscribes/gil/receipt.jpg', target='_blank')`

Comment: Hmm... when I simple open the route, for example `.../view/5abb6023d1eb870ba056be7b` in browser, everything OK, I see full page, NO errors, the error getting ony when open static file from this page...